# Writing matrix of ints to .txt

Tags: c, matrix

I'm trying to write a 479x639 matrix of `int`s to a `.txt` file. Preferably each line will include one entry followed by a `,`, so that I can input the data on MATLAB. I used the following code to try and write the raw data to a `.txt`:

```
FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
fwrite(output, sizeof(int), 479*639, f);    
fclose(f);
```

All I get is a `txt` with corrupted data. The rest of the program runs smoothly. Any suggestions?

Comment: The data is not corrupted; it is raw binary data, which you cannot read in a text editor. `fwrite`and `fread` are for raw data. In your case, you will have to write a nested loop with `fprintf`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out and tell me if it works

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int output[479][639];

    // Add values into output 2D matrix

    FILE *f = fopen("output.txt", "w");
    for (int i = 0; i < 479; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 639; j++) {
            fprintf(f, "%d, ", output[i][j]);  
        }
        fprintf(f, "\n");
    }  
    fclose(f);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i tried something like that, after @O Oehm's suggestion.Worked like a charm :)